# Disable automatic meeting creation (Google Calendar API)

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm interested in understanding the right way to create a new calendar event with version v3 of the Calendar API using a third party conferencing system: I'm unable to disable the automatic generation of meeting / hangouts videoconference rederence if it is requested in the individual user's calendar configuration.

I've tried some combination of the definition of the conferenceData nested object, but without success. The event contains always some reference to the videoconference link to Google meet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to remove/disable the default Google Hangouts. If you want to add a third party conferencing system, it will show next to Google Hangouts select box. Google Hangouts conferencing option is not an option that you can disable, it is default to calendar API. [See this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0fmy.png)